# php server update causes session decode to fail

Tags: php

My server recently updated PHP versions. I have a module that checks what is in the users shopping cart. The module uses `session_decode()` and since the update the module is showing this **error:**

> Warning: session_decode(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed on line 864

Lines 861-864:

```php
$session_data_cart = substr($session_data, $start_cart, $i);
$session_data_currency = substr($session_data, $start_currency, (strpos($session_data, ';', $start_currency) - $start_currency + 1));

session_decode($session_data_cart);
session_decode($session_data_currency);
```

I'm not really familiar with `session_decode()` but from what I can tell this code looks proper so I am not sure why I am getting that error.

here is the var_dump:

string(175) "cart|O:12:"shoppingCart":5:{s:8:"contents";a:0:{}s:5:"total";i:0;s:6:"weight";i:0;s:6:"cartID";N;s:12:"content_type";b:0;}language|s:6:"french";languages_id|s:1:"2";currency|s"

Comment: what does `var_dump($session_data_cart);` return ?

Comment: I added the dump to the question

Comment: I am having a very similar problem. Were you able to find the reason and solution?